# MySQL Stored Procedure echo "rows affected" instead of desired result?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, prepared-statement

Can anyone help me debug this Stored Procedure?  It completes the create successfully, but when I execute it in NaviCat, using the command:

```
CALL getJoinTables('data2013q3', 2013, 2);
```

While it does generate the view I create within the proc...

```
schema      table       alias
data2013q3  b2013q2a    a
data2013q3  b2013q2b    b
master  b2013q2t1   t1
master  b2013q2t2   t2
master  b2013q2t3   t3
```

NaviCat returns a messagebox declaring:

```
affected rows: -6
```

when the query should return a JOIN statement containing all of the aforementioned tables.  Here is my procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `common`.`getJoinTables`(IN strSchema varchar(35), IN iYr INT, IN iQtr INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE cursor_end CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';
DECLARE strPd, strTblPrefix, strBSearch, strMSearch VARCHAR(35);
DECLARE strSqlJoinTables VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE strTableSchema, strTable, strAlias VARCHAR(150);
DECLARE done, i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cur_tables CURSOR FOR SELECT strTableSchema, table_name, alias FROM common.vw_join_tables;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR cursor_end SET done = 1;

SET strPd = CONCAT(iYr, 'q', iQtr);
SET strTblPrefix = CONCAT('b', strPd);
SET strBSearch = CONCAT(strTblPrefix, '_');
SET strMSearch = CONCAT(strTblPrefix, 't_');
SET @strOut = '';
SET i=0;

SET @strSqlJoinTables = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW common.vw_join_tables AS SELECT table_schema, table_name, REPLACE(table_name, \'', strTblPrefix, '\', \'\') alias
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE (table_schema = \'master\' AND table_name LIKE \'', strMSearch, '\') OR (table_schema = \'', strSchema, '\' AND table_name LIKE \'', strBSearch, '\')
GROUP BY table_schema, table_name
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name' );

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS common.vw_join_tables;

SELECT @strSqlJoinTables;
PREPARE stmt from @strSqlJoinTables;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

OPEN cur_tables;
FETCH cur_tables INTO strTableSchema, strTable, strAlias;
read_loop: LOOP
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    IF i = 0 THEN
        SET @strOut = CONCAT(strTableSchema, '.', strTable, ' ', strAlias, ' ');
    ELSE
        SET @strOut = CONCAT(@strOut, ' JOIN ', strTableSchema, '.', strTable, ' ', strAlias, ' ON a.id=', strAlias, '.id ');
    END IF;

    SET i = i+1;
    FETCH cur_tables INTO strTableSchema, strTable, strAlias;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur_tables;

SELECT @strOut;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a [stored function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) instead of a stored procedure. The stored function can be defined to return a string.

For example, you could change your code like this (I'll leave out most of the details that don't change):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `common`.`getJoinTables`(IN strSchema varchar(35), IN iYr INT, IN iQtr INT) 
RETURNS LONGTEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE v_strOut LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';
...
RETURN v_strOut;
END
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
SELECT getJoinTables('data2013q3', 2013, 2);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right that I want to use a function, however, I am dynamically generating SQL and using prepared statements, which (as far as I know and read) are not allowed in a functions.

Comment: Ah yes, that is accurate. I didn't look closely at the body of your procedure.